# How to search for a line before a pattern using sed or grep

Tags: sed, grep, wildcards, pattern-matching

I have a log file `ouput.log` and the contents on the log file is as below. The log file comprises of multiple `.sql` files output in a sequential manner.
The log file will have which SQL file is being executed  example --> `@/opt/DBA/HIP/FILES/Environments/PRDO/347_WT_04NOV2020.sql` It can have 'n' number of sql statements from where it can error out any where with the pattern
ORA-. So whenever the command finds ORA-, I should get the file name for which has been errored out.

```
== Files executed in PRDO ==

== PRDO Execution spool ==
SQL> @/opt/DBA/HIP/FILES/Environments/PRDO/347_WT_04NOV2020.sql
SQL> ------UHIPOPS-36625---
SQL>
SQL> SET DEFINE OFF;
SQL>
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = HIS_PD;

Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO msg (MSG_ID,
  2                   LANG_CD,
  3                   SVR_CD,
  4                   MSG_DSC)
  5       VALUES (92012,
  6               'EN',
  7               1,
  8               'Please enter the EIN in the correct format: XX-XXXXXXX.');

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO msg (MSG_ID,
  2                   LANG_CD,
  3                   SVR_CD,
  4                   MSG_DSC)
  5       VALUES (92012,
  6               'ES',
  7               1,
  8               'Ingrese el EIN en el formato correcto: XX-XXXXXXX.');

ORA-

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO msg (MSG_ID,
  2                   LANG_CD,
  3                   SVR_CD,
  4                   MSG_DSC)
  5       VALUES (92012,
  6               'PT',
  7               1,
  8               'Introduza o EIN no formato correto: XX-XXXXXXX.');

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

SQL> @/opt/DBA/HIP/FILES/Environments/PRDO/348_WT_04NOV2020.sql
SQL> ------UHIPOPS-36625---
SQL>
SQL> SET DEFINE OFF;
SQL>
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = HIS_PD;

Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO msg (MSG_ID,
  2                   LANG_CD,
  3                   SVR_CD,
  4                   MSG_DSC)
  5       VALUES (92012,
  6               'EN',
  7               1,
  8               'Please enter the EIN in the correct format: XX-XXXXXXX.');

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO msg (MSG_ID,
  2                   LANG_CD,
  3                   SVR_CD,
  4                   MSG_DSC)
  5       VALUES (92012,
  6               'ES',
  7               1,
  8               'Ingrese el EIN en el formato correcto: XX-XXXXXXX.');

1 row created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO msg (MSG_ID,
  2                   LANG_CD,
  3                   SVR_CD,
  4                   MSG_DSC)
  5       VALUES (92012,
  6               'PT',
  7               1,
  8               'Introduza o EIN no formato correto: XX-XXXXXXX.');

ORA-

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

FOr example from the above log file I have executed two SQL files that has been captured and both has been errored with `ORA-`. Now is there a command or any way by which I can get the file names of the errored sqls? The output should be like below

```
347_WT_04NOV2020.sql
348_WT_04NOV2020.sql
```

All I know is basic `grep "ORA-" output.log` which will give me an output if ORA- is found in output.log

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output you want to see from this input. Also explain how we can recognize a file name in your output, how we can recognize an error,  and whether all files will contain at least one error.

Comment: Edited in detail

Comment: But how can we know the file name? Is a `@` followed by a `/` enough? Can there be cases where you have `@/foo` and `foo` is _not_ a file name? And what defines an error? Is it a line with only `ORA-`? Or can `ORA-` appear as part of a line that also has other data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'/' '/^SQL> @/{ filename=$NF; next } /^ORA-/{ print filename; }' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `sed` version with `xargs`:

```
sed -n '/^SQL> @/{s/^SQL> @//;h};/^ORA-/{g;p;}' output.log | xargs -L1 basename
```

- `-n` suppresses default output, so only lines with an explicit print command will be displayed
- The first `sed` match takes just the path and filename and holds it (`h`) in a buffer
- The second `sed` match gets the contents of the buffer (`g`) and prints it (`p`)
- `xargs` sends each line of output to `basename`, which displays just the filename portion